# Great computer-science speeches

Tags: language-agnostic

I've looked into some questions here where the "best" programming books are listed and then thought why there isn't a question concerning speeches yet. I think that speeches or presentations from developers or even creators of programming languages which were or are heavily used at some point are particulary interesting.

One of my favorite speeches was recommended to me by someone here on SO: [The future of C#](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL16/)
I also like Guido van Rossum's speeches but he sometimes seems pretty nervous.
Another in my opinion good presentation would be the Google tech talk about [Go](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKnDgT73v8s).

- Which (recorded) programming presentations/speeches are worth watching?

edit: Made this a community wiki as the answer would probably be a pretty long list.

Comment: I think this belongs in the same category as "great French victories of WWII" and "great school cafeteria food".

Comment: @MusiGenesis: type in google - "french military victories" and click on the top link :)

Comment: @Code Sherpa: I generally hate text-speak, but ROFLMFAO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[OMG Ponies!!! (Aka Humanity: Epic Fail)](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) is a Jon Skeet presentation that I'd consider one of the best speeches I've ever seen and the material is technical at times.

Answer (score 6):

If you've got the time, Abelson and Sussman's lectures accompanying the course "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs" are great:

http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/

Answer (score 4):

Herb Sutter's "Machine Architecture: Things Your Programming Language Never Told You":

http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-4714369049736584770
http://www.nwcpp.org/Downloads/2007/Machine_Architecture_-_NWCPP.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of Miško Hevery's testability talks.  They can be found on google techtalks.

Comment: Me too. He seems like a big follower of a 'religion' called test-driven :).

Answer (score 2):

Tony Hoare's [Null References: The Billion Dollar Mistake](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare) is pretty enlightening

Summary

Tony Hoare introduced Null references in ALGOL W back in 1965 “simply because it was so easy to implement”, says Mr. Hoare. He talks about that decision considering it “my billion-dollar mistake”.

Bio

Sir Charles Antony Richard Hoare, commonly known as Tony Hoare, is a British computer scientist, probably best known for the development in 1960, at age 26, of Quicksort. He also developed Hoare logic, the formal language Communicating Sequential Processes (CSP), and inspired the Occam programming language.

Answer (score 2):

Things a Computer Scientist Rarely Talks About by Don Knuth
Excerpt: http://cslipublications.stanford.edu/pdf/1575863278.pdf
Amazon: [http://www.amazon.com/Things-Computer-Scientist-Language-Information/dp/157586326X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157586326X)

Answer (score 1):

One of my favourites is Robert C Martin's talk on [Craftsmanship and Ethics](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/craftmanship-ethics).  It's basically a call to developers to act as professionals and demonstrate our pride in what we do by doing it well.